# Android Notification Center

Tags: wi-fi, notifications, wifi-tethering

I would like to send a notification to an android device pair with router in the same network , what is the best solution to make this true ?

The notification is just a text message , the requirement is if the device in the range covered by the Wifi range and paired . i want to send a notification as that in application notification